# How to start mySQL server detached in OS X at system startup?

Tags: mysql, macos, shell

I know I could start the server with

```
mysqld_safe
```

How can I start it detached and every time the system starts?

In which initialization file, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` or other, is good to put the server start command?

Comment: I find out that mysql.server start, starts the server, where is good to put that command?

Comment: I tried `~/.profile` nothing happened, and `~/.zshenv` load each time zsh is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the [OS X installer from MySQL.com](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) it includes a [preference pane](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html) that can be installed.  This includes options to automatically run on startup as well as viewing the current status of the MySQL server.

Comment: I had installed that, but had some path problems. So end up with installing with brew. I tried in System Preferences > User and Groups > Login Items, but there I can't explore /usr/local/bin/mysql.server